# Need assistance with 2D Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm in need of some help. Can anyone tell me how to get separate array values into the different TD elements? so "David" into id="name" and 28 into id="age"

JS:

```
var newArray = [["david", 28], ["Michael", 30], ["Martin", 21], ["Kevin", 25]];
var y=document.getElementById("Name");
var x=document.getElementById("randomNumber");
var z=document.getElementById("age");

x.innerHTML= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td id="Name" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Random Number</td>
        <td id="randomNumber"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td id="age"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: was able to sort it, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name = newArray[0][0];//result david
var age = newArray[0][1];//result 28
```

Answer (score 0):

To get "david" into the element with id `Name`, try:

```
y.innerHTML = newArray[0][0];
```

And to get age "28" into the element with id `Age`, try:

```
z.innerHTML = newArray[0][1];
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TAF3m/)